# How to print the Triangle in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to the python.
I tried to print a * triangle but wasn't unable to do so.

First I tried this:

```
new = int(input("Enter the line of stars \n"))
for i in range(1, new + 1):
    if (new - i) % 2 != 0:
        continue
    else:
        print(" " * ((new - i) / 2), i * "*")
```

*Got this error
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'*

Then I tried a different approach

```
new = 5  # int(input("Enter the line of stars \n"))
Fprint = True
for i in range(1, new + 1):
    if (new + 1 - i) % 2 == 0:
        Fprint = False
    else:
        Fprint = True
    if Fprint == True:
        print(((new - i)/2) * " ", i * "*")
```

But Iam still getting the same error.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your Error is, is that you are trying to multiply a String (non-int) by an float value.

```
((new - i)/2)
```

If new = 5 and i = 2. That means 5-2 = 3. If you divide this by 2, you will get 1,5. Then you are trying to multiply " " by 1.5x. Which is just not possible.
I do not have a code snippet on how to solve this issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def triangle(n):
    k = n - 1

    for i in range(0, n):

        for j in range(0, k):
            print(end=" ")

        k = k - 1

        for j in range(0, i + 1):
            print("* ", end="")

        print("\r")

n = 5
triangle(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
While dividing it return value as float and we need to convert it to int.

```
new = int(input("Enter the max stars \n"))
for i in range(1, new + 1):
    if (new - i) % 2 != 0:
        continue
    else:
        print(" " * int((new - i) / 2), int(i) * "*")
```